# Color refusing to change for certain text

Tags: c#, richtextbox, selection-color

I have no idea what could even possibly be causing this.

[image: Example]

So, I'm making an RPG for my midterm and the enemy stats screen won't cooperate with me.
The code will only color the first sentence in the player's stats while it does the entire thing on the enemy's. The code is identical and yet the coloration of the player's code refuses to work.

```
    private void DisplayStats()
    {
        richTextBox3.SelectionColor = Color.White;
        richTextBox3.AppendText("HP: " + E_HP + " \n ");
        richTextBox3.AppendText("STR: " + E_STR + " \n ");
        richTextBox3.AppendText("INT: " + E_INT + " \n ");
        richTextBox3.AppendText("DEF: " + E_DEF + " \n ");
        richTextBox3.AppendText("RES: " + E_RES + " \n ");

        richTextBox2.SelectionColor = Color.White;
        richTextBox2.AppendText("HP: " + P_HP + "/" + P_MHP + "\n");
        richTextBox2.AppendText("MP: " + P_MP + "/" + P_MMP + "\n");
        richTextBox2.AppendText("STR: " + P_STR + "\n");
        richTextBox2.AppendText("INT: " + P_INT + "\n");
        richTextBox2.AppendText("DEF: " + P_DEF + "\n");
        richTextBox2.AppendText("RES: " + P_RES + "\n");
    }
```

I have even tried giving the player and enemy separate methods and yet the player's stats still will only color the first line. Also, I have no clue why the enemy's text is misaligned. It looked like that before I even added color.

Comment: Why is the code only *practically* identical? Why is it not *actually* identical? It would seem like the safer bet.

Comment: *I have even tried giving the player and enemy separate private voids...*  The correct term for those 'private voids' is **[Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods)**

Comment: For them to be completely identical I'd have to put MP on the enemy (Which enemies don't have) and they'd be in the same text box. As for the "private void" thing I just forgot the term for a second.

Comment: `richTextBox2.ForeColor = Color.White;`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to LarsTech, who gave me the correct answer in the comments.

```
richTextBox2.ForeColor = Color.White;
```

I just replaced the second "selection color" with this forecolor command and that fixed it.
Again, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: The other way is `richTextBox2.SelectAll();  richTextBox2.SelectionColor = Color.White;`  at the end of your routine.